# Error while using docker run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm new to using Docker and I am trying to follow a tutorial on [this link](https://github.com/mlberkeley/oreilly-captions#option-a-use-our-pre-built-docker-image-from-docker-hub) which requires using a Docker. I have successfully installed the Docker on Ubuntu with the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-ce) tutorial.

I am following Option A and have completed steps 1,2, and 3. For 3 I had to precede the statement by `sudo` in order to get it work. However, when I try to run step 4 using the command `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v <path to repo>:/root mlatberkeley/showandtell`, I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint eager_pasteur (fb195057d626924#####################3d3d6f24071497fc443fbd8c9): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8888: bind: address already in use.
```

I have hashed some of the string of numbers above in the output error. I am new to Docker and I would be grateful for some suggestion to resolve the error.

Comment: Looks like some other programm ist using port 8888, you could try: -p 8866:8888

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be another process that is binded on port 8888.

To find this process run the command `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8888`. This will show you the process pid in the last column.

This might be a docker container that you have started previously. In that case try to remove the container by running `docker container ls` and then docker `container rm -f <container-name-from-prev-command>`. You can also start the new container on a new port, by replacing `8888:8888` with `9999:8888`.

Comment: When I ran "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8888" it returned : "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14462/python    
"

Comment: @spicyburrito This mean there is some python application with pid 14462 that is running on your machine that is binded to port 8888. You can kill this process using `sudo kill 14456` or use an alternative port as described in the answer.